# Is it possible to pass in a file as part of the request body using WireMock?

Tags: java, junit5, wiremock

I am currently writing an integration test using Wiremock. At the moment I am defining the id and organization id as parameters. Instead of repeating this process for say 50 fields, is it possible to pass in a JSON file as the request instead? ie use this file as the requestBody.

```
stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/v1/transaction"))
            .withRequestBody(
                    matchingJsonPath("$.data.id", containing("1")))
            .withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.data.organisation_id", containing("2")))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .withStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())
                    .withBodyFile("create_successful_response.json")));
```

Comment: requestBody is not a request body; the request body is transmitted by the client. What you are setting there are validations that will be performed on the request body.

Answer (score 2):

You might find that the placeholders feature added in 2.26.0 is a better fit for what you want here.

Placeholders allow you to use `equalToJson(...)` with looser matching of specific fields e.g.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "${json-unit.any-string}",
    "organisation_id": "${json-unit.regex}.*1.*}"
  }
}
```

More details here: http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#placeholders